# How to share data between components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a specific problem here.
I just want to share a variable that contains de array length of my main array from component 1 to component 2. This variable show be calculated in methods when the pages mount, so I'm using mounted() to call the method function.
This part is okay, so I must send this variable to child component so it can use on tags.

Let explain: I do have a component, lets name it 'progressBar', its code is simple, like on bootstrap-vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="main-progress">
      <div class="progress-wrapper">
        <b-progress
          v-model="value"
          max="100"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { BProgress } from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default ({
    components: {
        BProgress,
    },

    data(){
        return {
            value: 0,
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

and then I have the main array on component 1 called 'trailCard'

```
data(){
return{
trail_card: [
        {
          title: 'Card 1',
          description: 'Before you get into the nitty-gritty of coming up with a perfect title, start with a rough draft: your working title. What is that, exactly? A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics.',
          video: 'https://lp.planodevida.com/lps/o-que-e-etf/videos/o-que-e-etf_video_intro.mp4',
          video_thumb: require('@/assets/images/banner/jornada-thumb.png'),
          activeLike: false,
          activeFavorite: false,
          enable: true,
          completed: false,
          social: {
            like: 10,
            comments: 10,
            favorite: 10,
          },
          author:{
            avatar: '',
            name: 'Fulano de tal',
            slug: 'perfil-do-autor',
          },
        },
        {
          title: 'Card 2',
          description: 'Before you get into the nitty-gritty of coming up with a perfect title, start with a rough draft: your working title. What is that, exactly? A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics. A lot of people confuse working titles with topics.',
          video: 'https://lp.planodevida.com/lps/o-que-e-etf/videos/o-que-e-etf_video_intro.mp4',
          video_thumb: require('@/assets/images/banner/jornada-thumb.png'),
          activeLike: false,
          activeFavorite: false,
          enable: true,
          completed: false,
          social: {
            like: 10,
            comments: 10,
            favorite: 10,
          },
          author:{
            avatar: '',
            name: 'Fulano de tal',
            slug: 'perfil-do-autor',
          },
        },
]
      arrayLength: 0,
}
}
```

I'm calculating the arrayLength on methods using: function() return arrayLength = this.trail_card.length
The main question:
**How do I send this variable from trailCard (component 1) to progressBar (component 2) to use it on methods on component 2 or whatever I need to**

Comment: do they have the same parent?

Comment: With "whatever I need to" I assume that you may use arrayLength in the whole app. Saying that I'd recommend you to use vuex in order to avoid coupling your components. In your case, the trailCard component should hydrate your vuex state and any other component that needs to make use of arrayLength can just use mapGetters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have it all set up but use a computed property for the card array length, then you can emit the data when it changes, you can pass it as a prop to the progress bar, personally id also pass the cards to the trail cards as a prop.

```
<template>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            trail_card: [],
        };
    },
    watch: {
        trail_card(val) {
            this.$emit('cardAdded', this.cards);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        cards() {
            return this.trail_card.length;
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

```
<template>
    <progress-bar :cards="cards"></progress-bar>
    <trail-card @cardAdded="updateCards"></trail-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            cards: 0,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        updateCards(val) {
            this.cards = val;
        }
    },
}
</script>
```